# How to skip the run of a bat file at first trigger but run afterwards?

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I have scheduled this following task to repeat every XXX times after user login(this is when the bat file triggers). I want to skip/ not display the messageBox when it triggers (means when it runs at first time) but not in the following repetitions. Any suggestion on how to tackle this situation?

```
@echo off

SET client=Dear ABC,
SET MESSAGE=XYZ

@echo WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Popup "%client% %MESSAGE% & I will dissapear after 00 seconds.", 00, "title" > %TEMP%\wait.vbs 
wscript %TEMP%\wait.vbs
```

Comment: if (a particular file doesn't exists) then (create it and exit) else (execute);

Comment: What do you need the batch file code for? You could easily do this all in Vbscript.

Comment: You need to escape the `&` with `^&`, else you will have a 9009 error.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to approach this would be the following:

```
' Checks for the existence of a file which will
' serve as a flag, indicating if the script in 
' question has already been run or not, acting
' accordingly afterwards.

Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objFSO=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

homeFolder = objShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERPROFILE%")

flagFile= homeFolder & "\flag.txt"

If (objFSO.FileExists(flagFile)) Then

    ' Display your message
    msgbox("This is my message")

    '...(do other things you want)

Else

    ' Do not display your message

    ' Creates flag to indicate that
    ' this script has already been executed
    Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(flagFile,True)

    '...(do other things you want)

End If
```